# Have i got the right Derailleur

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano, derailleur-rear

Hello I have just brought a Shimano Tourney 7 speed derailleur for my carrera axel ltd 2015 but I was wondering if I have got the right one I'm not 100% sure. I have put the two links to each  bike and derailleur.  Will this derailleur work with this bike i have ordered this as a mounting bracket and not a direct mount was this a correct choice or should i have gotten a direct mount

Bike http://www.halfords.com/cycling/bikes/hybrid-bikes/carrera-axle-limited-edition-mens-hybrid-bike

Derailleur https://www.tredz.co.uk/.Shimano-RD-A070-7-speed-Road-Rear-Derailleur_61116.htm[image]

Comment: If you put a new derailer on there without replacing the chain and cluster you will be wasting your money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know, from that picture, and from their description, it is very difficult to tell what kind of rear derailleur that takes.  It says Tourney, but there are so many different derailleurs that have been made under the Tourney label, there is no telling from that.  It will become very apparent as you try to replace it whether you got the right one...

A Direct Mount rear derailleur will have a 5- or 6-millimeter recessed allen bolt threading into a hole in a bracket that is bolted to or part of the frame.

A Hanger Mount rear derailleur will have that bracket built into the rear derailleur and will instead tension into the back of a long dropout where you also mount the axle of the rear wheel, usually attaches with a Phillips screwdriver or a 9mm socket, tightening a nut that has a half moon shape.

That derailleur you bought has a direct mount on an extended hanger, and mounts as a direct mount.  Once you determine from the above descriptions which type you have, match the replacement to the same type.

Comment: Thanks I have added a picture of the part the derailleur mounts on to would my derailleur fit in or is it wrong sorry to keep asking I have never done anything with derailleurs. (Abit rusty I know ow bit we are replacing everything)

Comment: Now we see why you can't just compare the new derailleur to the old one :)

Comment: Forgot to say the old one snapped off aha

Comment: Although, looking at your pic more closely, is that not the old rear der. in the bottom right?